# Configure External domain to Openshift

Tags: redhat, wildfly8

I have Bronze package ,  http://jbosswildfly-hybridacumen.rhcloud.com/

i have 3 domain names hybridacumen.ie, hybridacumen.com, hybridacumen.eu

I set up my cname record for all three Domains to point to  jbosswildfly-hybridacumen.rhcloud.com/

on open shift i created three aliases for 3 domain names

but this does not work .
for one domain i get ssl error i do not have ssl cert or want ssl to be active

what i want is hybridacumen.ie/eu/com to point to my jboss app jbosswildfly-hybridacumen.rhcloud.com/

what steps am i missing

Comment: What is your domain name registrar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN the Domain DNS administration 
i created a CNAME record that points to hybridacumen.ie

so www points to hybridacumen.ie 
we dont need to modify A record as it is used only for IP Addresses in cloud hosting and even other wise its better to use cname record as ip address changes are encapsulated

ON Open shift 
i had created an alias  hybridacumen.ie and not www.hybridacumen.ie 
i deleted that alias and created a new one as www.hybridacumen.ie

then it started working